# How to disable onclickListener on listview item while doing pull to refresh on listview in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have implemented SwipeRefreshLayout, so i want to disable user interaction while layout is refreshing. I have implemented OnClickListener for ListView item. I am getting following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:791)
>   **at this line listView.setOnClickListener(null);  in onRefresh() method**.

How to solve this issue.

Here is my swipeRefreshLayout in onCreate()

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.CYAN);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(20);// in dips
        swipeRefreshLayout.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);// LARGE also can be used

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //Refreshing data on server
                listView.setOnClickListener(null);
                GetDataTask asyncTask2 = new GetDataTask();
                asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
        });
```

Here is my AsyncTask whichis call in onRefresh() method

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        currentPage = 1;
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        GetAllActivityList(currentPage);
        Loaddata();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

       if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
       {
           swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            populateList(OFFSET);
       }
    }
}
```

Here is Error Log information.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
            at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:791)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.CustomActionActivity$7.onRefresh(CustomActionActivity.java:563)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$1.onAnimationEnd(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:168)
            at android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView.onAnimationEnd(CircleImageView.java:107)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.finishAnimatingView(ViewGroup.java:6104)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16122)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your XML file

Comment: Actually there is no need to disable click or touch listener on listview if you are using SwiperefreshLayout, it is triggred when we swipe down vertically so it has nothing to do with touch and click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested remove `setOnClickListener()` as it is not meant for `AdapterView` and regarding disabling `ListView` click, apart from above solution, you can also do this , inside your `onListItemClick()` method you can use `if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())` for e.g.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapter, View view,int position, long arg){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
            // Handle Clicks
        } 
    }
```

**Edit**

as to disable button click, inside your `onClick()` method of `Button` you can use the same above condition,

for e.g

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
        // Handle Clicks
    } 
 }
```

Comment: But the problem is if button is appear in each list view item how can I disable while pull to refresh .

Comment: But button is in Adapter class and Adapter class is in different package so how can I do this .

Comment: You can pass your `Activity` or `Fragment` reference in your `Adapter` class constructor and from there you can call the same method,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111189/discussion-between-jandroid-and-satyen-udeshi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111198/discussion-between-jandroid-and-satyen-udeshi).

Answer (score 0):

It's not

```
listView.setOnClickListener(....);
```

It should be

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(...);
```

IF you want yo disable the view then use [`listView.setEnabled(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView** so first of all remove `setOnClickListener`.

Now regarding disabling your click, you can try with `setEnabled()` of `ListView`.

```
listView.setEnabled(false);
```

and after your list is refreshed

```
listView.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.CYAN);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(20);// in dips
        swipeRefreshLayout.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);// LARGE also can be used

        listView.setEnabled(false);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //Refreshing data on server

                    GetDataTask asyncTask2 = new GetDataTask();
                    asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                }
            });
```

And GetDataTask as..

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        currentPage = 1;
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        GetAllActivityList(currentPage);
        Loaddata();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

       if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
       {
           swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            populateList(OFFSET);
           listView.setEnabled(true);
       }
    }
}
```